# Multiple producer and multiple reader channel?

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency, parallel-processing, rust-cargo

Is it possible to create a channel in Rust with a non-determinate number of sends and reads in rust? Basically I want to send couple tasks up to channel as a form of an initialization and then start executing the tasks in a parallel way. But the problem is tasks themselves sometimes can create and send the tasks up to channel. The channel should close when all tasks have been consumed. I thought channel implementation would suit best for this particular case but Rust doesn't seem to have a multiproducer + multiconsumer channel implementation. Or suggestions of a completely new paradigm would also be welcome if I am trying to implement something I am not supposed to and / or is not possible.

Thank you!

Comment: The search term you're looking for seems to be "multiple producer multiple consumer" (or "mpmc"). There are plenty of crates available, check their documentation and find one that's likely to work for your use-case.

Answer (score -2):

You may use either `std::sync::mpsc` or `crossbeam_channel` the formal is better and faster but requires pulling an external crate.

Documentation of `std::sync::mpsc`:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/index.html

Documentation of `crossbeam_channel`:
https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/latest/crossbeam_channel/